# The impulse response of a LTI discrete system is $h[n]=\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^n u[n]$. Find the response of this system to the input $x[n]= e^{jnπ/4}$

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, frequency-response, impulse-response

Hi I'm trying to solve the problem when studying for an upcoming test.

The given solution is
$1.2503 e^{jnπ/4 -0.2991}$, and is found by computing $H(Ω)$ and evaluating this at $Ω=π/4$.
when I try this I get $H(π/4)=(1/3)^8=0.000152$ and therefore the convolution is $0.000152e^{jnπ/4}$.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong so any help would be appreciated so much!

Comment: You should first find the DTFT $H(\omega)$ of $h[n]$, then evaluate $H(\pi/4)$...

Comment: You should really explain how you evaluated $H(\pi/4)$ ...